# Semi Annual Deposit that earns 5% Compounded Quarterly

Tags: microeconomics, finance, accounting

I was asked:

> A man planned to endow 1000000 USD to his son on his son's 21'st
>   birthday. How much is his semi-annual deposit in a special account
>   that earns 5% compounded quarterly if the first deposit was made when
>   the son was 4.5 years old?

Answer is 16640.20 USD

My Solution:

Comparing Effective Rates:

$${ ER_{semiannually} = ER_{quarterly} }$$
$${ (1+i_{semiannually})^{m_{semiannually}} - 1 = (1+i_{quarterly})^{m_{quarterly}} - 1 }$$
$${ (1+i_{semiannually})^{2} - 1 = (1+0.05)^{4} - 1 }$$
$${ i_{semiannually} = 0.1025 }$$

Get the number of periods for Semi-Annual Payment

$${ 21-4.5 = 16.5 {yrs} }$$
$${ n = 16.5 \times 2 = 33 payments }$$

I am going to use the formula for Future Worth of Annuity since it is equal payments

$${ F = A\frac{ (1+i)^n - 1 }{i} }$$

Wherein

$${F = 1000000}$$
$${A = ? }$$
$${i = 0.1025 }$$
$${n = 33 }$$

I get an Annuity of 4265.165002

What am I doing wrong? is it not Future Annuity? Are my interest rates correct?

--
P.S. this isnt homework; this is for a board exam review in mechanical engineering. I don't know why they include finance/accounting in the "Engineering Economics" section but I have no solid background in business mathematics.

Comment: Most of us here don't care if it is homework, just if 1) Does it look like homework? (which this question does) and if so 2) Did you try to solve it and show your work? (which you did).  So this is a fine question.